# SOLUTIONTYPE option for Paypal Express Checkout in mobile web

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

What we expect are buyers can pay with credit card without having PayPal account.

But there is a conflict in Paypal documentation system we not really understand:

1, As the document "SetExpressCheckout API Operation (NVP)", we must set SOLUTIONTYPE option to "sole".

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

[image: SetExpressCheckout API Operation (NVP)]

2, In the document "Express Checkout on Mobile Devices", they said that "SOLUTIONTYPE" must be set to "mark".

[image: Express Checkout on Mobile Devices]

Does that means, in mobile web, Paypal does not allow to make payment without Paypal account? I think no, because with "SOLUTIONTYPE" set to "sole", we can pay with Credit card in almost cases.

What is the right way to do here?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SOLUTIONTYPE=SOLE works on a mobile Express Checkout flow.
2. **Mark** is done to override the PayPal website Preferences settings of 'PayPal Account optional' which is equal to 'Guest Checkout' (credit card option) PayPal Account is Optional
3. When this feature is turned on, your customers will go through an
   optimized checkout experience. This feature is available for Buy
   Now, Donations, and Shopping Cart buttons, but not for Subscription
   buttons. **PayPal Account Optional: [On] or [Off]**
4. The right way to do is according to what 'you' want to do; you can send
   SOLUTIONTYPE=SOLE to allow guest checkout with Express Checkout as
   this payment method is mobile optimized for you and will not hinder
   the payment options

Comment: Thank you so much, @PayPalGuy. Your answer gives us needed info to resolve the issue. Now it works like as charm :)

Comment: @PayPalGuy Please kindly have a look, I need you help brother 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262762/using-api-calling-account-as-receiver-account

Comment: @Dong - sorry for late reply, I am glad you got it up and running 8^)

Comment: Hi Bibek - you cannot pay yourself in any form of 'send' api call; in this matter you are sending and receiving with the same merchantID username. All you have to do is create a new buyer sandbox account and use that ID as one of the receivers. This response is expected design.