# Using API calling account as receiver account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, activemerchant

I'm trying to integrate Paypal Adaptive checkout using [Active Merchant](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant) and [active_paypal_adaptive_payment](https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment) gem. 
During User registration, User needs to register his/her paypal account in order to receive the payment during the transaction.

I've setup all the credentials for activemerchant. While registering user Account in paypal I got the following error.

> You are logging into the account of the API caller of this
>   transaction. Please change your login information and try again.

[image]
Is it possible to use same API calling account as secondary receiver during checkout?

Thank you, Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Too late to answer you back, but my knowledge in PayPal is limited to REST API to be very true.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Chain Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/) where the API caller email address and the secondary receiver email address are the same. You get this error `You are logging into the account of the API caller of this transaction. Please change your login information and try again.` when you are using the api caller's email as the sender of the payment.

```
receiverList.receiver(0).email = YYY@gmail.com
receiverList.receiver(0).amount = 5.00
receiverList.receiver(0).primary = true
receiverList.receiver(1).email = XXX@gmail.com `this can be the api caller's email address as well`
receiverList.receiver(1).amount = 2.00
receiverList.receiver(1).primary = false
feesPayer = EACHRECEIVER
```

Comment: I'm doing chained payment.But I've connect to paypal button which got redirect to Paypal and returns with the email address and I'm using this email to send amount in future.I'm getting above mentioned issue is while login into the Paypal. Chained payment is working good.

Comment: I'm not getting any correlation Id in my logs, Since it occurs in Paypal page.

Comment: what is the email address of api caller and the email address used in checkout page, show us the api request and response

Comment: API username:  `vikas-facilitator_api1.esignature.com.np`
checkout email is `vikas-facilitator@esignature.com.np`

Comment: checkout email vikas-facilitator@esignature.com.np is the sender of payment, not receiver

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97966/discussion-between-bibek-sharma-and-vimalnath).